# Find End Date based on Start date and Duration - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table for packages, where each package consists of Number of Days, Days included [any day(s) Sunday, Monday, ... ]

```
Package   | Duration | Days Included
-------------------------------------------
Package 1 | 10 days | '1,2,3' [Sun, Mon, Tue] 
Package 2 | 15 days | '4,5,6,7' [Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]
Package 3 | 30 days | '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' [Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]
etc
```

When customer selects any package (selecting the start date), I need to calculate the expiry date of that package based on the no. of days and days included in that package.

I need to create a function in which will return the **Expiry Date** providing 
the following 3 inputs.

1. Start date
2. Number of days
3. Days to be included

Example:

> For Package 1, starting from 13-Mar-2016, Correct End Date should be:
>   03-Apr-2016 
>   (10 days would be 13,14,15,20,21,22,27,28,29 March, 03
>   Apr)

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
 DECLARE @NoDays INT
 DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
 SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DD, @NoDays, @StartDate)
```

So far I have done this, but it is including all 7 days.

Can anybody help how only the specific days can be included to get the correct expiry date?

Comment: Please, explain how *Days Included* works

Comment: Also, post a correct `EndDate` example given a certain `StartDate`, `NoDays`, and *Days Included*

Comment: @har07 I have edited the question with one sample. Ask me if its still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Numbers table and calendar table,i have created some test data which uses normalized version of your packagedays table.

```
---package table
create table packagetable
(
id int,
maxduration int
)


insert into packagetable
select 1,10


----storing number of days in normalized way
create table packagedays
(
pkgid int,
pkgdays int
)

insert into packagedays
select 1,1
union all
select 1,2

create function dbo.getexpirydate
(
@packageno int,
@dt datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin

declare @expiry datetime
;with cte
as
(
select date,row_number() over ( order by date) as rn from dbo.calendar 
where wkdno in (select pkgdays from packagedays where pkgid=@packageno ) and date>=@dt
)
select @expiry= max(Date)+1--after last date of offer add +1 to get next day as expiry date
from cte
where rn=(select maxduration from packagetable where id=@packageno)

return @expiry
end
```

if you don't want alter daysincluded as normalized version,you might have to use tally function which does the same and add it in cte

You can see calendar table [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/)

Comment: Basically i have the normalized table, I mention here just for better understanding. Thanks. Let me try your solution

Comment: you need to create calendar table first before running my solution

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/

Comment: I think this logic is better than while loops (in other answers). However calendar table creation is the only additional effort.

Comment: yep,we have to create once and it is invaluable

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @NoDays INT
DECLARE @DaysIncluded VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME, @LOOP INT, @Count int

SET @StartDate = getdate()
SET @NoDays = 10
SET @DaysIncluded = '1,2'
SET @LOOP = @NoDays


SET @EndDate = @StartDate

WHILE (@LOOP > 0)
BEGIN

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @EndDate)
print @EndDate
Select @Count = Count(1) from dbo.splitstring(@DaysIncluded) where name in (DATEPART(dw,@EndDate))

if(@Count > 0)
BEGIN
print 'day added'
SET @LOOP = @LOOP - 1
END

END
```

if you want the function dbo.splitstring, please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Comment: I have not included the current day in the expiry calculation, so if you want to include that, put the statement SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @EndDate) after the IF block

Comment: I need only Expiry Date in return :(

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '3/13/2016'
DECLARE @NoDays INT = 10
DECLARE @DaysIncluded varchar(50) = '1,2,3,4'

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(d, -1, @StartDate)

DECLARE @IndexOuter INT = 1
DECLARE @IndexInner INT = 1
DECLARE @AuxDate DATETIME

while @IndexOuter <= @NoDays
begin

    set @IndexInner = 1

    while @IndexInner <= 7
    begin
        SET @AuxDate = DATEADD(d, @IndexInner, @EndDate)

        IF DATEPART(DW, @AuxDate) in (select IntValue from ConvertCsvToInt(@DaysIncluded))  
        begin
            set @EndDate = @AuxDate
            break
        end

        set @IndexInner = @IndexInner + 1
    end

    print @EndDate

    set @IndexOuter = @IndexOuter + 1
end

select @EndDate
```

To see ConvertCsvToInt function [click here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-a-csv-with-an-in-sub-select)